# Multidimensional arrays on Oracle Tutorials

Tags: java

I am going through the Oracle tutorials on Java and there is one thing I do not understand so far. This is why the outcome of the arrays is what is shown.

The code is:

```
public static void main (String [] args){

      String[][] names = {
                {"Mr. ", "Mrs. ", "Ms. "},
                {"Smith", "Jones"}
            };
            // Mr. Smith
            System.out.println(names[0][0] +
                names[1][0]);
            // Ms. Jones
            System.out.println(names[0][2] +
                names[1][1]);
        }
```

I understand that Mr gets printed out as the index is 0. But smith gets printed out when it is [1][0], and also I understand how Ms is printed out because the index is 2. But I do not understand how Jones is printed out.

What I don't understand is how the multidimensional arrays use the indexes.

Please correct me if I am wrong but do multidimensional arrays work like rows? So the first array would be 0 and the next array would be 1 and so on?

Which is why [1] which is the second array and [0] is equal to "Smith" because it is the index 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String[] titles = names[0]; // {"Mr. ", "Mrs. ", "Ms. "}
String[] lastNames = names[1]; // {"Smith", "Jones"}
```

> But I do not understand how Jones is printed out.

The first index of `names` selects the `String` array to pick from, while the second index is the element of that array that is picked.

Just as `"Smith"` is `lastNames[0]`, which is `names[1][0]`, `"Jones"` is `lastNames[1]`, which is the same as `names[1][1]`.

> Please correct me if I am wrong but does multidimensional arrays work like rows. So the first array would be 0 and the next array would be 1 and so on?
>
> Which is why [1] which is the second array and [0] is equal to "Smith" because it is the index 0?

This is correct.

Answer (score 2):

The first index select one of the following two arrays:

- `names[0]` is

  ```
  {"Mr. ", "Mrs. ", "Ms. "}
  ```
- `names[1]` is

  ```
  {"Smith", "Jones"}
  ```

The second index selects one of the elements of that array.

Thus:

- `names[0][0]` is `"Mr. "`
- `names[0][1]` is `"Mrs. "`
- `names[0][2]` is `"Ms. "`
- `names[1][0]` is `"Smith"`
- `names[1][1]` is `"Jones"`

Answer (score 0):

Your array stores these values as follows

```
names[0]  [0] | [1] | [2] | 
     Mr   Mrs    Ms 

names[1]  [0] |  [1] 
         Smith  Jones
```

That's why

```
System.out.println(names[0][2] +
                names[1][1]);
```

prints   Ms. Jones

Hope this helps you.